# LAMP attendance system

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

i just cant get the right approach to this problem, i have two arrays .
first array $attendance which has the following keys and values

```
Array
(
[attendance] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 0
    )
```

This is coming from a checkbox if checked value is 1 else value is 0
The second array is $remark

```
[remark] => Array
    (
        [1] =>
        [2] => 
        [3] =>  'sick'
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] =>  'leave'
        [7] =>  'On assignment'

    )
```

Now this is what the key 1- 7 stands for, the script is for employee's attendance the key 1-7 is the employeeID in the employee table in my database.

Now what i want to achieve is concatenate the array in such a way to look like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [employeeID] => 7
        [attendance] => 0
        [remark] => 'On assignment'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employeeID] => 6
        [attendance] => 0
        [remark] => 'leave'
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [employeeID] => 5
        [attendance] => 1
        [remark] => 
    )

//and so on
)
```

I am using Codeigniter If i am able to concatenate it i will also love to know how i will insert the multiple data into the employee table which looks like this,

```
employee's table
employeeID | date | status | remarks
```

the date i planned using CURDATE() then status will hold either 0 or 1 from attendance
**Again**: the keys from 1- 7 both on the remark and attendance's array is the employeeID

update!!
this is what i tried but did not work.

```
$att = $_POST['attendance'];
$remarks = $_POST['remark'];

foreach($att as $employee_id=>$status)
        {
            $x=0;
            $employee[$x]['employee_id']=$employee_id;
            $employee[$x]['status']=$status;


            foreach($remarks as $employee_id=>$remark)
            {

                $employee[$x]['remark']=$remark;
                $x++;
            }
       }
```

Comment: What do you have so far? This is some fairly trivial array manipulation.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attendance = $_POST['attendance'];
$remarks = $_POST['remark'];

$collect = array();
foreach ($attendance as $employeeID => $attending) {
    $collect[] = array(
        "employeeID" => $employeeID,
        "attendance" => $attending,
        "remark" => isset($remarks[$employeeID]) ? $remarks[$employeeID] : ""
    );
}

$values = array();
foreach ($collect as $entry) {
    $values[] = "(" . ((int) $entry["employeeID"]) . ",
        CURDATE(),
        " . ((int) $entry["attendance"]) . ",
        '" . sql_escape($entry["remark"]) . "'
    )";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `attendance`
    (`employeeID`, `date`, `status`, `remarks`)
    VALUES
    (" . implode(",", $values) . ")";
```

Make sure you replace `sql_escape` by the appropriate escape function. If you're using PDO use that.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough, to be honest...

```
$numOfEmployees = 8;

$concatArray = array();

foreach($attendance as $k => $v)
{
     $concatArray[] = array("employeeID" => $k, "attendance" => $v, "remark" => $remark[$k];
}
```

If your attendance table is in anything like SQL, you could go about it with `foreach` on the above mentioned concatArray:

```
foreach($concatArray as $key => $value)
{
     $remark = $value['remark'];
     // sanitize remark for database
     $query = "INSERT INTO employees (ID, Date, Status, Remarks) VALUES ({$value['employeeID']}, NOW(), {$value['attendance']}, '{$value['remark']}');";
     // perform the actual query
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a very general example, making a lot of assumptions about the database.

As Frits notes, the remark field should be sanitized, perhaps by using `mysqli_real_escape_string` for MySQLi or `quote` for PDO - depends on what you are using.

Comment: There is no guarantee that all `$i` are employeeIDs. As you can see there is no employee with id `0`. Just do a `foreach` over `$attendance` to get the actual employeeIDs. Also, if my remark is `He's late again`, that will break your query ;)

Comment: Thank you, I did my best to include your advice in the answer :)